# Insert output IDs into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a status table, and another table containing additional data. My object IDs are the PK in the status table, so I need to insert those into the additional data table for each new row.

I need to insert a new row into my statusTable for each new listing, containing just constants.

```
declare @temp TABLE(listingID int)

insert into statusTable(status, date)
  output Inserted.listingID into @temp
select 1, getdate()
from anotherImportedTable
```

This gets me enough new listing IDs to use.

I now need to insert the actual listing data into another table, and map each row to one of those listingIDs -

```
insert into listingExtraData(listingID, data)
select t.listingID, a.data
from @temp t, anotherImportedTable a
```

Now this obviously doesn't work, because otherDataTable and the IDs in @temp are unrelated... so I get far too many rows inserted.

How can I insert each row from `anotherImportedTable` into `listingExtraData` along with a unique newly created `listingID`? could I possibly trigger some more sql at the point I do the `output` in the first block of sql?

**edit**: thanks for the input so far, here's what the tables look like:

*anotherImportedTable*:

```
data
```

*statusTable*:

```
listingID (pk), status, date
```

*listingExtraData*:

```
data, listingID
```

You see that I only want to create one entry into `statusTable` per row in `anotherImportedTable`,  then put one `listingID` with a row from `anotherImportedTable` into `listingExtraData`... I'm thinking that I might have to resort to a cursor perhaps?

Comment: What is in the second table that tells it which record you want it to relate to? Please be more specific about the structure and use of the second table. Incidentally, never use implicit joins. What you have is a cross join which relates every record of the first table toe very record of the sencond table.  Even if you wanted that, it is better to use explicit syntax so that people maintaining know what you intended and that the cross join wasn't an accident.

Comment: @HLGEM I completely agree, it's a bit off a mess, hence me ending up here :) thanks for your input - more detail provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how you can do it (if I'm right about what you actually want to do):

```
insert into listingExtraData(listingID, data)
select q1.listingID, q2.data
from 
   (select ListingID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by ListingID) as rn from @temp t) as q1
   inner join (select data, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by data) as rn from anotherImportedTable) q2 on q1.rn = q2.rn
```

In case you matching logic differs you will need to change sorting of anotherImportedTable. In case your match order can not be achieved by ordering anotherImportTable [in one way or another] then you're out of luck.

Comment: ah interesting use of ROW_NUMBER() OVER, thanks for that, I'll see how it goes.